# WSO2 property mediator value from property file

Tags: wso2, esb

Can I get the property by key from the property file and set it to the property of the mediator in wso2. Maybe i can the set property from the property file? Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: could you please explain your requirement, do you need to read a file an extract property value into a wso2 synapse property?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a script mediator which loads the file then you can fetch the desired property and set it `mc.setproperty(key,value)` inside the javascript